# Which frequent flyer card to use?

Tags: europe, loyalty-programs, lufthansa, miles-and-more, aegean-airlines

I am new to these programs, and my flight is always the Athens-Munich ale re tour, with a Lufthansa flight (booked via the Lufthansa website). I fly on the economy class, with my hand luggage only.

I have a Miles & Bonus (Aegean) and a Miles & More (Lufthansa) frequent flyer card, both on the basic tier (I didn't have any upgrade).

Which card should I use in order to maximize the miles I earn?

Edit: I am only interested in using these miles to book my next ATH-MUC flight with Lufthansa, via Lufthansa website.

---

My attempt:

Aegean has these rules:

[image]

For Lufthansa, as @jcaron said, you earn 4 miles per euro ([src](https://www.miles-and-more.com/online/portal/mam/uk/earn/flight/offer?nodeid=2507840&l=en&cid=1000243)).

Comment: I don't understand why you say the page you linked is only applicable for domestic flights within Germany. I don't see anything on the page to suggest that's the case. The words 'domestic' and 'Germany' don't even appear on the page, and it mentions non-domestic flights (Innsbruck, Salzburg, or Graz <-> Frankfurt/Main) as being particularly affected by the introduction of this system.

Comment: Lufthansa seem to have changed the way miles are accrued based on the sales channel. If you buy from the LH website, you will get miles based on the price, while if you buy through other channels, it's based on distance or a flat rate. In your case, as you're buying from the LH website, it would be based on the price paid.

Comment: Can't find the actual ratios on their site, it's probably only available once logged into your account or through the LH app.

Comment: Note that beyond miles earned, you should also check the cost of the awards you're  intending to use.

Comment: @jcaron yeah I couldn't find that either, but I am not logged in. For Aegean, I found them without being logged in! I am interested in consuming these miles to reduce the amount of money I am paying for my next flight. Chris, I mean in the animation, edited. Still though, it's unclear to my novice eyes, that's why I am asking for help from the experienced ones.

Comment: There's supposed to be a mile earning calculator in the Miles & More app (that's what the site says at least). Not sure how it works exactly. It also says you get 5K bonus miles for using the app :-)

Comment: Ah, found it: https://www.miles-and-more.com/online/portal/mam/uk/earn/flight/offer?nodeid=2507840&l=en&cid=1000243 4 miles per euro (or 125 miles minimum). 6 miles per euro if you have status.

Comment: @gsamaras it's hard to verify that without knowing exactly what you chose at each step, but I took a best guess based on the info in the post and got the same result you describe but with no mention of it being domestic-only. The FAQs on the page seem consistent with that, too.

Comment: Seems that I will need to that app eventually @jcaron, thanks (500 miles though)! OK, good find, so that's essentially the x4 info I found myself already, since I am a basic user. Now, it would be great if I could compare them somehow... Chris H, now, after my last edit, I think the information are enough for a comparison...

Comment: How often do you fly? The Lufthansa miles expire after a few years, which is not the case with A3 if you have a transaction every few years.

Comment: Not much @DCTLib, 5-6 times per year. Based on what you said and the answer of Itai, I think that I should choose Aegean, since in both I have the same amount of miles at this moment.

Comment: You have to be careful with the booking classes. If you always buy deep discount economy tickets, which might be in booking classes K, E, L or T, the you don't earn any miles at all with Aegean Miles+Bonus.

Comment: @dunni I have no idea what booking class my already booked flights are, and I can't find these info in the Lufthansa website of my bookings.. I will it in mind for the next flight I'll book. I bought the ticket without any offer in play, I just went to the Lufthansa website, and book the flight (maybe it was the cheapest flight), do you think that this falls in the category "deep discount economy tickets"? I can see only economy light on my booking.

Comment: If you open your booking on the website, go to Flight Details, then you see something like "Premium Economy (N)" on each flight. The letter in the brackets is the booking class.

Comment: This is what I did @dunni, but I only get Economy Light...I searched for a mapping online, but couldn't find one (Economy Light -> booking class)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the miles you get from a single flight is the same with both cards, either cards will maximize the number of miles you get for that one flight. When you get a more advanced tier level, some programs have a multiplier which makes a difference, for example getting 1.25 miles for each mile flown, instead of 1.

The main point is not maximizing the number of miles for a flight but maximizing your balance so that you get to a reward level before the points expire. In that case, you should use the card for which you have the most points with already. Unless you fly truly a lot, the best advice is to keep only one program active per alliance since that will make you reach an award level faster.

Comment: Aegean's miles seem to expire later than the ones of Lufthansa ([comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/130587/which-frequent-flyer-card-to-use?noredirect=1#comment322893_130587)), and I have the same amount of miles pretty much at that point..thanks Itai, you help me fly! :)

Comment: I don't understand how the miles you get are the same for both cards? Aegean gives a fixed number of miles based on booking class, while Lufthansa gives 4 miles per euro spent. Makes comparisons quite difficult, one would have to make a number of simulations to see which one gives the best results overall (probably depends how far ahead OP books).

Comment: Also, if you only buy the cheapest Lufthansa tickets, you might not earn miles at all with Aegean Miles+Bonus (booking classes K, E, L, T are exluded, which are the cheapest discount classes).

Comment: Must be relatively new. I used to have both cards too but consolidated, so must have missed some of the recent program changes. I will check them out.